# Why can't I link against shaderc?

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, static-linking, vulkan

I have a vulkan project that is trying to use shaderc.

The library was installed under the following path (linux system):

```
./libraries/shaderc/build/libshaderc
```

Doing `ls` in this directory gives:

```
CMakeFiles                         shaderc_combined_shaderc_test
cmake_install.cmake                shaderc_c_smoke_test
CTestTestfile.cmake                shaderc_shaderc_cpp_test
libshaderc.a                       shaderc_shaderc_private_test
libshaderc_combined.a              shaderc_shaderc_test
libshaderc_shared.so               shaderc_shared_shaderc_cpp_test
libshaderc_shared.so.1             shaderc_shared_shaderc_private_test
shaderc_combined.ar                shaderc_shared_shaderc_test
shaderc_combined_shaderc_cpp_test
```

The documentation provided with the library explicitly states:

> 3. If the external project does not use CMake, then the external project can instead directly use the generated libraries. 
>      `shaderc/libshaderc/include` should be added to the include path, and
>      `build/libshaderc/libshaderc_combined.a` should be linked. Note that
>      on some platforms `-lpthread` should also be specified.

I attempt to link the project as follows using make:

```
g++ -o "../build/VulkanEngine" obj/Debug/DebugCallback.o obj/Debug/Device.o obj/Debug/log.o obj/Debug/ImageViews.o obj/Debug/Instance.o obj/Debug/Pipeline.o obj/Debug/RenderPass.o obj/Debug/Surface.o obj/Debug/SwapChain.o obj/Debug/VkExtensionsStubs.o obj/Debug/GLFW_tools.o obj/Debug/main.o    -L../libraries/glfw-3.2.1/bin -L../libraries/glm/bin/glm -L../libraries/vulkansdk-linux/1.1.97.0/x86_64/lib -L../libraries/shaderc/build/libshaderc -lstdc++fs -lglfw -lglm_static-lvulkan -llibshaderc_combined.a
```

In particular notice the argument `-L../libraries/shaderc/build/libshaderc`: and the argument `-llibshaderc_combined.a`

As you can see the specified linking path matches the installation path (libraries/ contains all the third party libraries my project uses).

However the linker complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibshaderc_combined.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [VulkanEngine.make:119: ../build/VulkanEngine] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:30: VulkanEngine] Error 2
```

So it seems I messed up the path somehow, but I don;t know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-lname` linkage option directs the linker to search in specified
(`-Ldir`) and default library search directories for either of the
files `libname.so` (shared library) or `libname.a` (static library). If it finds either of them them it searches
no more directories and inputs that file to the linkage. If it finds
both of them in the same search directory then it will prefer `libname.so`.

So change:

```
-llibshaderc_combined.a
```

to:

```
-lshaderc_combined
```

You must also be sure that `-lshaderc_combined` appears in the linkage
sequence *before* any other library that it depends on, and *after* any object file or library that depends upon it, or the linkage
is liable to fail with undefined reference errors.